# does std::map::end() return different results from different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I've got this [thread pool](https://github.com/tbrown122387/ssme/blob/0302b6c5c2056ad676618ffe186b7e4b0f83b1cd/include/ssme/thread_pool.h#L228) that holds a container of objects, and whenever it receives a new piece of data, it updates all the objects with the same new piece of data.  The work is preallocated on the construction of the thread pool, and this work is stored in the following data member

```
std::map<std::thread::id, std::vector<unsigned>> m_work_schedule
```

So if a thread's element in this `map` has the elements 1,2 and 3 in its `vector<unsigned>`, that means it is responsible for updating the objects with indexes 1,2 and 3 every time a new data point arrives.

If I have ten objects and three threads, the work schedule might look something like this

```
140314357151488... 2, 5, 8, 
140314365544192... 1, 4, 7, 
140314373936896... 0, 3, 6, 9,
```

In every [worker thread](https://github.com/tbrown122387/ssme/blob/0302b6c5c2056ad676618ffe186b7e4b0f83b1cd/include/ssme/thread_pool.h#L288), it does some calculation and then adds its calculation to the shared aggregate variable. I'm confused though, because **once all the threads are finished, only the final thread is supposed to put the finishing touches on the calculation.** For some reason, this block is *occasionally* executing twice:

```
if( std::prev(m_work_schedule.end())->first  == std::this_thread::get_id() ){
    std::cout << "about to finalize from thread " << std::this_thread::get_id() << ", which supposedly is equal to " <<  (--m_work_schedule.end())->first << "\n";
    m_working_agg = m_final_f(m_working_agg);
    m_out.set_value(m_working_agg);
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
139680503645952... 2, 5, 8, 
139680512038656... 1, 4, 7, 
139680520431360... 0, 3, 6, 9, 
about to finalize from thread 139680520431360, which supposedly is equal to 139680520431360
................
about to finalize from thread 139680503645952, which supposedly is equal to 139680503645952
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error'
  what():  std::future_error: Promise already satisfied
```

**How can this block of code run twice, though?** I am only reading from `m_work_schedule`, but the occasional nature of this suggests it's some sort of race condition. I'm struggling to think of any possible explanation for this, though.

- Does a `std::map::end()` return different things in different threads?
- Does one thread's reading with `std::map::end()` affect another thread's?**
- If the last thread finalizes before all threads are finished working, can it randomly enter this block of code again?
- Can thread ids change?

Comment: Shouldn't the message `about to finalize from thread 139680520431360, which supposedly is equal to 139680520431360` come from two different thread ids?

Comment: @BillLynch yes, see my edit. I think I'm showing you some output from some modified code I've been experimenting with. I remember the early runs using the code I linked to showed different ids. Apologies.

Comment: Can we see what the synchronization between threads looks like?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz there is only one mutex that protects the one thing that they all write to: `m_working_agg` tIt's acquired a few lines above: https://github.com/tbrown122387/ssme/blob/0302b6c5c2056ad676618ffe186b7e4b0f83b1cd/include/ssme/thread_pool.h#L308

Comment: Taking a look at the repository, the synchronization is broken. `split_data_thread_pool` is modifying shared resources (like `m_work_schedule`) while the threads are running, and nothing guarantees all the work is actually done when the final average occurs.

Comment: ok yeah maybe `std::map::end()` is getting called before the work has all been distributed thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet your problem is here

```
        for(unsigned i=0; i< m_num_threads; ++i) {
            m_threads.push_back( std::thread(&split_data_thread_pool::worker_thread, this));
            most_recent_id = m_threads.back().get_id();
            m_work_schedule.insert(std::pair<std::thread::id, std::vector<unsigned> >(most_recent_id, std::vector<unsigned>{}));
            m_has_new_dyn_input.insert(std::pair<std::thread::id, bool>(most_recent_id, false));
        }
```

you are starting the threads while you are still populating the m_work_schedule_map. And as far as I can see there is no lock. So you have simultaneous readers and writers

Comment: yep, that's it. Now fixed--I added an extra all-work-distributed condition to check before starting any work so it doesn't prematurely check the end with `std::map::end()`

Comment: @Taylor it would be nice if there was a way to create a thread but not start it until you are ready. But there isnt